# 21.04: Use Active Directory option grayed out

Tags: active-directory, 21.04

I am trying to set up Ubuntu 21.04 to use Active Directory.

I have the VM installed on a ESXi host connected to AD.  AD is 2016 schema, on-site, not Azure.  The VM does get a correct IP address (I verified in DHCP).  The VM does not have internet access, though.

When I get to the point in the install where it asks for username, password, etc., there is an option at the bottom that says "Use Active Directory".  Everything I have read says to click that checkbox, but I cannot as it is grayed out.

[image]

I have tried this with an an AD object already created, non existent, everything.  I've downloaded the ISO and tried a few times now.  Is there something that I am missing?  I've searched around but it appears this is too new and not a lot of people have tried to mess with it yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

you need to have an internet connection for this option to enable itself.